# Disable format source by region

Tags: delphi, ide, format

I'm using Delphi Seattle.

I'd like to know if there is a way to define regions where `Format Source` doesn't act.

For example, I have the following code:

```
JSONObjectBuilder
    .BeginObject
        .Add('MyKey1', 'MyValue1')
        .Add('MyKey2', 'MyValue2')
        .Add('MyKey3', 'MyValue3')
        .BeginObject('MyObject1')
        .EndObject
        .BeginObject('MyObject2')
            .Add('MyKey4', 'MyValue4')
            .Add('MyKey5', 'MyValue5')
            .Add('MyKey6', 'MyValue6')
            .Add('MyKey7', 'MyValue7')
            .BeginArray('MyArray1')
            .EndArray
            .BeginArray('MyArray2')
            .EndArray
        .EndObject
    .EndObject;
```

If I press `ctrl+D` it becomes:

```
JSONObjectBuilder.BeginObject.Add('MyKey1', 'MyValue1').Add('MyKey2', 'MyValue2').Add('MyKey3', 'MyValue3').BeginObject('MyObject1')
        .EndObject.BeginObject('MyObject2').Add('MyKey4', 'MyValue4').Add('MyKey5', 'MyValue5').Add('MyKey6', 'MyValue6').Add('MyKey7', 'MyValue7')
        .BeginArray('MyArray1').EndArray.BeginArray('MyArray2').EndArray.EndObject.EndObject;
```

I use `Format source` constantly and I'd love it could be possible.

Comment: add `//` to the end of each line. But this does not prevent Delphi remove indentation

Comment: If you are using this as **data**, you could also `$INCLUDE` this as separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comment of @kami I've tried the following way:

```
JSONObjectBuilder
{ }.BeginObject
{ ____ }.Add('MyKey1', 'MyValue1')
{ ____ }.Add('MyKey2', 'MyValue2')
{ ____ }.Add('MyKey3', 'MyValue3')
{ ____ }.BeginObject('MyObject1')
{ ____ }.EndObject
{ ____ }.BeginObject('MyObject2')
{ ________ }.Add('MyKey4', 'MyValue4')
{ ________ }.Add('MyKey5', 'MyValue5')
{ ________ }.Add('MyKey6', 'MyValue6')
{ ________ }.Add('MyKey7', 'MyValue7')
{ ________ }.BeginArray('MyArray1')
{ ________ }.EndArray
{ ________ }.BeginArray('MyArray2')
{ ________ }.EndArray
{ ____ } .EndObject
{ }.EndObject;
```

It isn't beautiful, but for me it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 3):

No, the IDE does not support excluding areas of the source from formatting.

The only viable alternative I've been able to find is to selectively format by highlighting specific blocks of code and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to format just that block.